# Chrome Extension Edit Specific Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to only edit a specific iframe with my content script. In my iframe, I have a website (i'll use facebook as an example) that I would like to edit to remove a specific element. I am able to do that without any problem but let's say the user goes to facebook.com outside of the iframe, the website will be edited too. I am looking for a way to only edit the website within the iframe.

Comment: Use the standard js approach: check if top == window

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that. @wOxxOm